# Was bedeutet: "ich schreibe als erstes, was gegen ihre Anschaffung spricht."?

Tags: meaning, translation, meaning-in-context

https://youtu.be/CWGsVuoBoTA?t=359

Was bedeutet "**Anschaffung**" und "**spricht**" in diesem Fall?

Comment: Hello Marcus and welcome to the site. We have a policy here, that we handle translations requests carefully. Please tell us about your own research. Surely you already looked them up in a dictionary. Can you tell us why that didn't help you? That way we can give you a well-tailored answer.

Answer (score 1):

In dem Video geht es um die Struktur einer Erörterung und an der genannten Stelle wird die Abfolge von Pro und Kontra d.h. der Argumente erläutert.

Mit `Anschaffung` wird meist der Kauf einer (teuren) Sache mit einer längeren Nutzungsdauer bezeichnet (larger acquisition). Es `spricht` etwas für oder gegen die Anschaffung. Die folgenden Beispiele füge ich an:

> Also schreibe ich als erstes (in der Reihenfolge auf), was gegen ihre Anschaffung spricht.

So I write down first (in order) what speaks against their purchase.

> Welche Argumente sprechen gegen die Anschaffung eines Tablets?

What are the arguments against the purchase of a tablet?